# Load layout file based on platform version in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, portability

I know I can create `/layout-v7`, `/layout-v8`, `/layout-v11` folders to allow my app to load the suitable layout for different platform.

BUT, the above way needs me to create different layout folders for all needed platforms.

I would like to have only **two layout folders**, if my app is running on platform with API version **>= 11** , it loads from `layout-x/`, **otherwise** load layout files from `layout-y/`.

**How to achieve this?**

Comment: create them all in one layout folder with different names and just check the `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` value to load a correct one.

Comment: @ Sergey, I have done the same thing as you said before I post. Just wonder is there any other workaround for my purpose.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad way to do it, really. It's fine. If you want to follow standard procedures then use multiple folders as they suggest it.

Answer (score 7):

> I would like to have only two layout folders, if my app is running on platform with API version >= 11 , it loads from layout-x/, otherwise load layout files from layout-y/.

Create `res/layout-v11/` and `res/layout/`. And you're done.

Comment: But if my app is running on a platform with API version 13, will the app load layout files  from layout-v11 ??

Comment: Then just create 3 folders :)

Comment: "But if my app is running on a platform with API version 13, will the app load layout files from layout-v11 ??" -- yes.

Comment: Both folders have same no. of files?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. The answer above prompted me to change the way I was doing it. I had a folder called 'layout-v8' and 'layout', thinking that if it matched to v8 it would use that one, and any other folder would match the regular layout.

So if you find it using the wrong folder, switch the way you handle the folder names. In this example, I created a 'layout-v11' which is v11 and greater, then my normal 'layout' folder is 10 and below.